# .Net C# POSTing to controller method not working

Tags: c#, .net, post, postman, httpclient

In my controller I have a method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EjecutarModeloProgramado(Guid id, [FromQuery] int anyo, [FromQuery] int mes)
{
    ModeloProgramadoEnqueueDTO model = new ModeloProgramadoEnqueueDTO
    {
        Id = id,
        FechaEjecucion = new DateTime(anyo, mes, DateTime.DaysInMonth(anyo, mes)),
    };

    if (Mediator.Send(new ModeloProgramadoEnqueueCommand(model)).Result)
    {
        Success(message: "Se ha encolado el trabajo");
    }
    else
    {
        Error("No se ha podido encolar el trabajo, compruebe que no se encuentre ya en ejecución");
        return Json("Error");
    }

    return Json(data: "OK");
}
```

And I need to do a call to that method from a test.

I've made several attempts to no avail.

The next piece of code looks dirty, but the commented lines are kept for you to see some of my different attempts.

```
var ejecutarModeloUrl = "https://localhost:7117/Pools/Management/EjecutarModeloProgramado?anyo=2023&mes=6"; 
//4b4516a4-c0a5-493e-9bd1-08dbe9c20c33?anyo=2023&mes=6";

//Guid id, [FromQuery] int anyo, [FromQuery] int mes

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramt2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id","4b4516a4-c0a5-493e-9bd1-08dbe9c20c33")
    //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("anyo", "2023"),
    //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mes","6")
};
HttpContent q2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramt2);

//var str = "{\"anyo\": 2023,\"mes\": 6}";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("anyo", "2023");
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("mes", "6");
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ejecutarModeloUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(ejecutarModeloUrl, q2).Result;
}
```

The response in most cases is 200, but the case is the breakpoint in the destination "EjecutarModeloProgramado" method is never hit, while if I do the request from Postman the breakpoint works as expected.

[image: Postman request screenshot]

Edit 1: Adding more relevant info.

When I say "*from a test*" I mean from a test method in a test project.
Another relevant comment is that I have another post request in the same test method to do login, and the breakpoint I've set in the "Login" method is being hit correctly, so I clearly guess it's a problem in the way I'm defining the parameters for the second request.

The full test method:

```
[Fact]
public async void Modelo761_001()
{
    #region Login (THIS LOGIN REQUEST WORKS AND HITS THE CORRESPONDING BREAKPOINT)

    var loginUrl = "https://localhost:7117/Login/Acceder";

    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramt = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName","XXX"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password","XXX")
        };
    HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramt);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(loginUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(loginUrl, q).Result;
    }

    #endregion

    //THIS NEXT REQUEST DOES NOT HIT THE CORRESPONDING BREAKPOINT AT THE BEGINNING OF THE METHOD

    try
    {
        var ejecutarModeloUrl = "https://localhost:7117/Pools/Management/EjecutarModeloProgramado?anyo=2023&mes=6"; 
        ///4b4516a4-c0a5-493e-9bd1-08dbe9c20c33?anyo=2023&mes=6";

        //Guid id, [FromQuery] int anyo, [FromQuery] int mes

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramt2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id","4b4516a4-c0a5-493e-9bd1-08dbe9c20c33")
            //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("anyo", "2023"),
            //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mes","6")
        };
        HttpContent q2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramt2);

        //var str = "{\"anyo\": 2023,\"mes\": 6}";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("anyo", "2023");
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("mes", "6");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ejecutarModeloUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(ejecutarModeloUrl, q2).Result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Edit 2: More relevant info.

Now I got the problem. Even if I'm doing login before calling the endpoint that I need to test, the login is not persisting, is getting lost.

This is the method I need to test header:

```
[HttpPost]
//[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Alto, Medio")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EjecutarModeloProgramado(Guid id, [FromQuery] int anyo, [FromQuery] int mes)
{
```

And I have just realized that uncommenting the "Authorize" rule it just works, the breakpoint is hit as expected, and this is the reason the Login is working, login has no "Authorize" decorator.

Then, my new problem is the login.

Comment: When you say "from a test" - do you mean you're using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing`? If so, then you need to understand that in that case the website is not actually accessible via a normal TCP connection, instead the `HttpClient` instances must be created from `WebApplicationFactory` which communicates with the webapp via internal channels. [You'll need to read this article thoroughly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: Thanks for your input @Dai, and yes, I mean from a Test project, but why it is working fine from Postman then? Postman is also doing an external call, and the breakpoint is hit. And what is more, I have another post request in the same test method to do login, and the login breakpoint is being hit with no problems.

Comment: Presumably because you aren't using `WebApplicationFactory` in your test project.